# knnclassify and knnsearch give different results

Tags: matlab, classification, nearest-neighbor, knn

I'm using *knnclassify* to do a kNN classification in Matlab and it's working well. Now, I need to know the distances to the neighbors and it seems that *knnsearch* funcion gives me that.

The problem is the results are not the same. I am quite sure *knnsearch* is not working properly, but I don't know the reason.

This is my code:

```
k=1;
distance='euclidean';
rule='nearest';

%kNN classification
result = knnclassify(sample_matrix, training_matrix, label_matrix,k,distance,rule);

%showing which element is recognized and the distance to it
[recognition,distances] = knnsearch(training_matrix, sample_matrix,'k',k);
```

So, result and recognition should be the same, and then I can see the distances.

This is result:

> 4 1 1 2 4 1 1 4 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
>   4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
>   8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

And this is recognition:

> 3 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 4 3 3 4 3
>   4 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 5 5 6 6 6
>   7 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 7 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

(They're supposed to be two vectors).
The desired result is

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
>   4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8
>   8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

So, result is almost well (good enough) and recognition is a disaster.
As you can see the beginning is much better than the end.
Anybody can help me??
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain what format your data have and also the difference / roles of `sample_matrix`, `training_matrix` and `label_matrix`? And the dimensions as well

Comment: training_matrix and sample_matrix contain float valoues between 0 and 2 (approx), they correspond to miosignals. training_matrix size  is 360x3200 and sample_matrix 90x3200 (they are both extracted from the original data matrix, 450x3200), label_matrix is a 360x1 matrix containing the "names" of what there is in training_matrix. The idea of knnclassify is to compare the elements in sample_matrix with the elements in training_matrix and say which is the correspondent (if sample_mat(1,:)=training_mat(4,:), it says sample_mat(1,:) = label_mat(4,:), which is the name (class 1, for example). @dan

Comment: On the other hand, if I do this little example it works:
`sample = [.9 .8;.1 .3;.2 .6];

training=[0 0;.5 .5;1 1];

group = [1;2;3];

foo_classify = knnclassify(sample, training, group);
[foo_search,dist] = knnsearch(training, sample);
`
The results are:
`
foo_search =

     3
     1
     2

foo_classify =

     3
     1
     2

dist =

    0.2236
    0.3162
    0.3162`